# Ajax call not working in grails

Tags: jquery, grails

I have the following code in my gsp page

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#searchButton").click(function(event){

           var form = $j('#federatedSearchForm');
           $j.ajax({
                       type:'POST',
                       url:'/tabulae/federatedSearch/ajaxGetSearchResults',
                       data:form.serialize(),
                       cache:false,
                       error:function(request,status,error) {
                           alert(status)
                       },
                       success:function(data,status,xhr) {
                           alert(data);
                         },
                       complete:function(xhr,status) {
                       }

               });

           });
   });
```

I have the folllowing code in my controller

def ajaxGetSearchResults = {

```
   log.debug "params:" + params

   def returnResults = federatedSearchService.search(params)


   render returnResults as JSON
```

}

What I'm seeing is that before the controller completes the request. The success method is called on the client side. Is there something I'm doing wrong or in-correct ?

Comment: Does the request ever reach the controller method?
Also, what is the content of the response?

Comment: Yes it does. The alert in the success is fired before even the controller can return data and hence the data is coming in empty. When I log data in the controller, I do see that there is data, seems like the call to the service is async.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` from your click handler will prevent the browser's default action (likely a form submission):

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#searchButton").click(function(event){
        ...

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to use

event.preventDefault() before the ajax call